# Copying file on AWS s3 with different name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, duplicates, copy

I have test.zip file on aws s3. and now i want to create new file test1.zip with copy of test.zip.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), then you can use:

```
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/test.zip s3://my-bucket/test1.zip
```

You can do the same operation using `CopyObject()` using an [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/developer/tools/) with your favourite programming language.